# Proving the minimum of an expected value is greater than the expected value of a minimum

Tags: statistics, expected-value, jensen-inequality

I am looking to prove that $\min_{a \in \mathbb{R}} E[f(a, X)] \geq E[\min_{a \in \mathbb{R}}f(a, X)]$ where $f: \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f$ is guaranteed to have a minimum, and $X$ is some random variable with an unknown distribution.

This looks similar to Jensen's Inequality for a concave function where $\min_{a \in \mathbb{R}(\cdot)}$ would be the function of interest. If this is the case, I am not sure how to prove that $min_{a \in \mathbb{R}}(\cdot)$ is concave. If there is a simpler way, then it is eluding me and any help is wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, if $X \le Y$ and both have expectations you have $EX \le EY$.

Assuming the relevant expectations exist, for any $a'$ you have $E f(a',X) \ge E \min_a f(a,X)$ and
so $\inf_{a'} E f(a',X) \ge E \min_a f(a,X)$.

Comment: Could you start your second paragraph with "for any $a'$ and $x$ you have  $f(a',x) \ge  \min_a f(a,x)$ and thus $E f(a',X) \ge E \min_a f(a,X)$ ..." ?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. There are an infinite number of ways of expressing that sentence.

Comment: Why the downvote?